# Retrieve text from dynamically created texboxes from repeater control selections

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to pass the user selections from the controls generated by a repeater (checkboxes, dropdownlist, textboxes) to a datatable and use that as a data source to a gridview for testing and eventually to a stored procedure as a table variable parameter.

When there are no selections for some checkboxes, the corresponding textboxes are not generated and the code throws an exception (`check to determine if the object is empty before calling the method`).

The part that seems to be causing the issue is when I pass the text from the texboxes to the datatable. When I pass the checkbox names it works fine; I am trying to overcome this by checking if the text box control is generated but it still throws the same exception.

Is there a better way to check if the dynamic textbox is generated?

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable Frs = new DataTable("udtMParameters");
    Frs.Columns.Add("MName", typeof(string));
    Frs.Columns.Add("IsNum", typeof(string));
    Frs.Columns.Add("MValue1", typeof(string));
    Frs.Columns.Add("MValue2", typeof(string));
    try
    {

        foreach (RepeaterItem i in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            CheckBox fn = i.FindControl("chk") as CheckBox;
            CheckBox isn = i.FindControl("ChkboxIsNumeric") as CheckBox;
            PlaceHolder plc = i.FindControl("PlcMFilter") as PlaceHolder;
            TextBox s = i.FindControl("start") as TextBox;
            TextBox l = i.FindControl("end") as TextBox;
            DropDownList d = i.FindControl("value") as DropDownList;


            if (fn.Checked)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = fn.Text;
                if (isn.Checked)
                {
                    DataRow dr = Frs.NewRow();
                    dr["MName"] = fn.Text;
                    dr["IsNum"] = "Y";
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Text))
                    {
                        dr["MValue1"] = s.Text;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr["MValue1"] = " ";
                    }
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Text))
                    {
                        dr["MValue2"] = l.Text;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr["MValue2"] = " ";
                    }

                   Frs.Rows.Add(dr); 
                }

                else
                {
                    DataRow dr = Frs.NewRow();
                    dr["MName"] = fn.Text;
                    dr["IsNum"] = "N";
                    dr["MValue1"] = "MValue1";
                    dr["MValue2"] = "MValue2";
                    Frs.Rows.Add(dr);

                }
            }

            this.GridView1.Visible = true;
            GridView1.DataSource = Frs;
            GridView1.DataBind();


            panel2.Enabled = true;
            panel2.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please include the details of the exception you're getting, and what line in your code throws the exception.  This will help people to help you.  You can use the [edit] link below your question to add that information. Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: I did more research on my problem and found that the issue is the dynamically created controls are not retained at post back and I need to recreate them at page load , but I still dont know how to persist the user selections in these text boxes and pass them to a datatable.

Comment: The controls will maintain themselves once you recreate them.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail , don't I need to recreate them with the user selections ? how do I do that

Answer (score 0):

Replace you casting realized with as by parenthesis, in order to localize your null object

```
TextBox s = (TextBox)i.FindControl("start");
TextBox l = (TextBox)i.FindControl("end");
```

On event of a conversion failure, casting with parentheses will raises an exception, while casting with as will yields a null.